# Have 2 Lambda expressions within the same function call each other

Tags: c++, lambda, sfml

I've been using SFML for a project, and I'm attempting to make a pause state while still using the SFML game loop. Long story short, I have been attempting to use 2 Lambda expressions within the same function to toggle between the pause and run states I have running. Here's some example code:

```cpp
int main() {
  //some stuff here...
  auto pauseloop = [&] {
    //do some stuff here...
    runloop();
  }
  auto runloop = [&] {
    //some more code, include SFML game loop here...
    if (paused)
      pauseloop();
  }
  runloop();
}
```

This works fine at first, but runs into an issue almost immediately: upon calling `pauseloop()` from within `runloop()`, I cannot call `runloop()` from within `pauseloop()`. I tried to add something to the effect of this above my `main()` function:

```cpp
auto pauseloop = [&] {}; //initializer
auto runloop = [&] {}; //initializer
```

However, after some extensive testing and debugging, this causes the `runloop()` Lambda expression above the `main()` function to be called when being called from `pauseloop()`, however the *intended, fully declared,* `runloop()` is called when called at the end of the `main()` function.

First, is there any way to get two Lambda expressions from within the same function to call each other? Second, why does the `pauseloop()` expression call the initializer version of `runloop()`, while the `runloop()` at the end of `main()` calls the intended one? From my best guess, I would have assumed that because `runloop()` and `pauseloop()` were both initialized defined before either one was called, the `pauseloop()` would call the declared version, as it had been read in its entirety and correctly overwritten the initializer, yet this seems completely off compared to what is actually happening. Thank you in advance!

Edit 1: To be concise, the above attempts don't work for the intended solution (having Lambda expression "a" call Lambda expression "b" and vice versa). How would I write two Lambda expressions that can?

Comment: What does "the initializer version of runloop()," mean? "This works fine" suggests that the shown code compiles, but it doesn't. The question is unclear. It might seem at first that this is a classical case of having to use type erasure and `std::function`, but then the mentiob of "the initializer version of runloop()" makes everything completely unclear. Can you [edit] your question, and reframe it as a single, concise, question that clearly explains what's being asked?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik simply put, how would I write two separate Lambda expressions within the same function that can call each other whenever needed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as your lambdas have captures, and it seems like yours do, you can't have them call each other directly because there is a circular dependency when you declare them. To work around this, you can assign them to pointers.

If you did not have captures, the compiler would simply generate anonymous functions for your lambdas and you could assign them to function pointers like this:

```cpp
void (*pauseloop)() = nullptr;
void (*runloop)() = nullptr;

pauseloop = []() {
    //...
    runloop();
    //...
};

runloop = []() {
    //...
    pauseloop();
    //...
};
```

Since you do have captures, the solution is very similar but you would use `std::function` instead. Actually, since you can use `std::function` with functions as well, this is my recommendation in any case:

```cpp
std::function<void()> pauseloop, runloop;

pauseloop = [&]() {
    // ...
    runloop();
    // ...
};

runloop = [&]() {
    // ...
    pauseloop();
    // ...
};
```

Note that, in both cases, it is not going to be enough to capture the function pointer / `std::function` by value. At least one of the lambdas will have to capture it by reference or use it as a global. Otherwise it will only capture the initial `nullptr` value.

https://ideone.com/c7FGCo

Answer (score 0):

As you have discovered, simply using each of them through capture will create a circular dependency. An alternative to it is to pass them as arguments.

Let's start with the `runloop`. Rather than getting the `pauseloop` through capture, you can pass it as an argument:

```cpp
auto runloop = [&](auto const& pauseloop) {
    if (pause) {
        pauseloop();
    }
};
```

And later you can call it like: `runloop(pauseloop);`

Similarly, you would give `pauseloop` an argument:

```cpp
auto pauseloop = [&](auto const& runloop) {
    runloop();
};
```

However, now in the `pauseloop`, you were calling `runloop()`, despite `runloop` actually requires a parameter. Similarly, in `runloop`, you are calling `pauseloop()` despite `pauseloop` also requires a parameter. To fix it, you can also pass the parameter that should be called in them to the outer function:

```cpp
auto runloop = [&](auto const& runloop, auto const& pauseloop) {
    if (pause) {
        pauseloop(runloop, pauseloop);
    }
};

auto pauseloop = [&](auto const& runloop, auto const& pauseloop) {
    runloop(runloop, pauseloop);
};
```

Now, you would call `runloop` and `pauseloop` like:

```cpp
runloop(runloop, pauseloop);
pauseloop(runloop, pauseloop);
```

---

However, that final call interface is pretty verbose. To make it simpler, you can separate the interface and the implementation for each of them:

```cpp
auto _runloop_impl = [&](auto const& runloop, auto const& pauseloop) {
    if (pause) {
        pauseloop(runloop, pauseloop);
    }
};

auto _pauseloop_impl = [&](auto const& runloop, auto const& pauseloop) {
    runloop(runloop, pauseloop);
};

auto runloop = [&] {
    _runloop_impl(_runloop_impl, _pauseloop_impl);
};

auto pauseloop = [&] {
    _pauseloop_impl(_runloop_impl, _pauseloop_impl);
};
```

Now, you can simply call them like:

```cpp
runloop();
pauseloop();
```

- <sup>***Note***, you only need to define the interface lambda if you intend to call them directly.</sup>

---

And if you have many different types of loop to add into the logic, you can potentially use parameter pack to easily pass all arguments around:

```cpp
auto _runloop_impl = [&](auto const& ... loops) {
    auto loops_tuple = std::tuple{std::cref(loops)...};
    switch(state) {
        case State::PAUSE:
            std::get<1>(loops_tuple)(loops...);
            break;
        case State::MENU:
            std::get<2>(loops_tuple)(loops...);
            break;
        case State::SHOP:
            std::get<3>(loops_tuple)(loops...);
            break;
    }
};

auto _pauseloop_impl = [&](auto const& ... loops) {
    auto loops_tuple = std::tuple{std::cref(loops)...};
    std::get<0>(loops_tuple)(loops...);
};

////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// ... similar implementations for other loops
//
////////////////////////////////////////////////////


auto runloop = [&] {
    _runloop_impl(
        _runloop_impl,
        _pauseloop_impl,
        _menuloop_impl,
        _shoploop_impl
    )
};


int main() {
    runloop();
}
```